# Multi-lined html output using a decorator

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When you just need to return one line of html, decorators are great!

However, I don't know how I should conditionally render a complex, multilined section of HTML, such as this:

```
<% if current_user == @user || current_user.is_admin? %> 

    <h3> Private Info: </h3> <h4> - Only <%= @user.is_owner? %> can view this information </h4>

    <p><strong>First Name:</strong> <%= @user.decorate_first_name %> </p>
    <p><strong>Last Name:</strong>  <%= @user.decorate_last_name %></p>
    <p><strong>Email:</strong> <%= @user.decorate_email %> </p>

<% end %>
```

As you can see, I'm wrapping it in an if statement, which is exactly what I want to replicate with a decorator, but I'm not sure how.

Should I create a partial and render the partial with a decorator?

*app/decorators/user_decorator.rb:*

```
def decorate_private_info
    h.render 'private_info' if current_user? || admin?
end
```

Comment: IMO thats the correct way to go. I wouldn't go with awesome's solution below as it mixes presentation logic into the model layer. Generally you wouldn't need a decorator - just a partial should suffice as the presentation is specific to that partial.